# How to return HTTPMovedPermanently (301 status) instead HTTPFound (302) in pyramid notfound_view_config

Tags: python, pyramid, http-status

Using **notfound_view_config** in pyramid with parameter **append_slash=True**, i get 302 http status when redirecting, but i want set custom http status - 301.

`@notfound_view_config(append_slash=True, renderer="not_found.mako")
def notfound(request):
   return {}`

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPFound seems to be hard-coded in `AppendSlashNotFoundViewFactory`, but you may use its code as an inspiration for your "not found view":

```
from pyramid.interfaces import IRoutesMapper
from pyramid.compat import decode_path_info

@notfound_view_config(renderer="not_found.mako")
def notfound(request):
    path = decode_path_info(request.environ['PATH_INFO'] or '/')
    registry = request.registry
    mapper = registry.queryUtility(IRoutesMapper)
    if mapper is not None and not path.endswith('/'):
        slashpath = path + '/'
        for route in mapper.get_routes():
            if route.match(slashpath) is not None:
                qs = request.query_string
                if qs:
                    qs = '?' + qs
                raise HTTPMovedPermanently(location=request.path+'/'+qs)
    return {}
```

(untested, treat as pseudocode)

Comment: AppendSlashNotFoundViewFactory makred as deprecated in pyramid version 1.3

Comment: I've borrowed the code from Pyramid 1.5b1 and I can't see it being deprecated there. At any rate - my code does not use  `AppendSlashNotFoundViewFactory` at all - it just uses it as example of how to iterate over your route declarations trying to find one that matches.

Answer (score 1):

My solution with deprecated class:

`class append_slash_notfound_factory(AppendSlashNotFoundViewFactory):
    def __call__(self, context, request):
        result = super(append_slash_notfound_factory, self).__call__(context, request)
        if isinstance(result, HTTPFound):
            return HTTPMovedPermanently(result.location)
        return result`